# Solve the equation $4\sqrt{2-x^2}=-x^3-x^2+3x+3$

Tags: systems-of-equations, radicals

Solve the equation in $\Bbb R$:
$$4\sqrt{2-x^2}=-x^3-x^2+3x+3$$
Is there a unique solution $x=1$? I have trouble when I try to prove it.

I really appreciate if some one can help me. Thanks!

Comment: try working with this $$
(x+1)\left(x^2-3\right)+4\sqrt{2-x^2}=0
$$

Comment: I'm sorry! But I don't understand your hint!

Comment: hint: $-1\le x\le\sqrt{2}$

Comment: @ sepideh: What's happen if $x \ne 1$ It means $[-1; \sqrt{2} ] \setminus \{1\}$?

Comment: @sepideh How did you bound $x\geq -1$?

Comment: What about $x \in [-1;1) \cup (1;\sqrt{2}]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's rewrite it and try to solve it:

$$4\sqrt{2-x^2}=-(x+1)(x^2-3)$$

Squaring both sides (this will keep originial solutions but introduce new ones) gives

$$16(2-x^2)=(x+1)^2(x^2-3)^2$$

Moving everything over, expanding, and then factoring by the root we already had (when $x=1$) yields

$$(x-1)(x^5+3x^4-2x^3-14x^2+5x+23)=0$$

Now as the second factor is a degree $5$ polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$, it has at least one real root. (In fact, it has only one root since the derivative $f'(x)$ of the polynomial $f(x):=x^5+3x^4-2x^3-14x^2+5x+23$ has only two roots but I'll try to think of a better argument than this).

Making a translation $x=-1+y$ simplifies the right factor to

$$f(y)=(y^5-2y^4-4y^3+20y+8)=0$$

To see there is a solution $y$ in $[-1,0)$ note that $[f(-1)=-11,f(0)=8)$ so by the intermediate value theorem there is a solution in $y\in [-1,0)$.

So if this was a solution to our original relation, we would have $x\in [-2,-1)$ but this can't be the case since we may restrict solutions of our original equation to $[-1,\sqrt{2}]$ following the argument of Paul Vergeev.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite the expression as 
$$ 16(2-x^2) = (x+1)^2(x^2-3)^2 $$
Note that the right hand side is non-negative so the left hand side should be too. Does it help?

**EDIT:** As Eoin points out, keep in mind that both sides of the original equation have the same sign only on $[-1;\sqrt2]$.

Comment: No, because now you've introduced a solution between $[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$

Comment: @Eoin All solutions must be in this interval, assuming we don't want to work with complex numbers.

Comment: Certainly if $x$ satisfies $f(x)=0$ then $f(x)^2=0$ but not conversely. By squaring the relation you introduce a solution $y\in [-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$ ($y\neq 1$) which does not satisfy the original relation. It still remains to be shown that this latter solution does not satisfy the original relation.

Comment: @Eoin Yeah, but if you say that absolute value of $x$ is less than or equal to 2 before squaring, you'll be fine, won't you?

Comment: No because $|y|\leq \sqrt{2}$ so $y$ satisfies those constraints still.

Comment: @Eoin OK. The right hand side of the original equation is less than 0 on $(-\infty; -\sqrt3)$ and on $(-1; \sqrt3)$. The left hand side is less than 0 is on $(-\sqrt2; \sqrt2)$ so they are both negative or equal to 0 on $[-1; \sqrt2]$. Keeping that in mind, can one limit the set of possible solutions and square both sides?
(Actually, I'm not arguing but trying to understand where I'm mistaken)

Comment: @PaulVergeev This works.

Comment: @Eoin from $4 \sqrt{2 - x^2} = (1+x)(3 - x^2)$ we know that $|x|\le\sqrt{2}$ also because left is always positive, right should be too.$|x|\le\sqrt{2}\Rightarrow |x|\le\sqrt{3}\Rightarrow 3-x^2\ge 0$ so one factor is always positive in the range $-\sqrt{2}\le x\le\sqrt{2}$ in order for the other to be positive we have $x\ge -1$ so $-1\le x\le\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 1):

It can be seen that $4 \sqrt{2 - x^2} = (1+x)(3 - x^2)$ leads to the expanded form, after squaring both sides and combining terms,
$$ x^6 + 2 x^5 - 5 x^4 - 12 x^3 + 19 x^2 + 18 x - 23 = 0 .$$
It is readily identified that $x=1$ is a solution and can then be factored out leading to
$$ (x-1)( x^5 + 3 x^4 - 2 x^3 - 14 x^2 + 5x + 23) = 0.$$
The polynomial of order $5$ has one real solution and $4$ complex solutions.

Comment: how do you find the real root of the polynomial of order 5?

Comment: @sepideh Newton, for example.

Comment: @sepideh There are various root finding methods that can be used, but if that is not the main theme of the problem then Wolfram Alpha, or related, is the most utilized modern method.

Comment: Note that not all roots of this degree 6 polynomial will necessarily solve the original problem (even if they are real)

Comment: Of course, I know the equation $x^5+3x^4-2x^3-14x^2+5x+23=0$ has one real root in $(-2,-1)$ because $f(-2) f(-1) <0$ and "So if this was a solution to our original relation, we would have $x \in [−2,−1)$ but this can't be the case since we may restrict solutions of our original equation to $[−1,\sqrt{2}]$ following the argument of Paul Vergeev".
" . What about $4$ complex solutions? 0_o????? How we can show that $x \not \in \Bbb R$??????????

Comment: @kimtahe6 If you can show it's monotonically increasing in $(-\infty,-1)$ and strictly positive in $(-1,\infty)$ that would do it. (That's how the graph looks, not saying it's a necessarily easy argument).